# Can dependent variables have zero mutual information?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

Let $X,Y$ be random variables. Assume that $X \sim N(0,1)$, and $X|Y \sim N(y,1)$.

**Is this possible?** What seems counter-intuitive to me is that this has the following properties:

1. Clearly, knowing $Y$ is relevant for $X$: The distribution of $X$ depends on $Y$. i.e. $p_{X|Y}\neq p_X$.
2. But nevertheless, the mutual information $I(X;Y)$ is zero.

If we extend the density functions of $X$ and $Y$ we get:

$$p_X=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p_{X|Y}\cdot p_Ydy$$

So we get

$$c_1\cdot e^{-\frac {x^2} 2}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty c_2\cdot e^{-\frac {(x-y)^2} 2}\cdot p_Ydy=c_1\cdot e^{-\frac {x^2} 2}\cdot\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {c_2}{c_1}\cdot e^{-\frac {y^2-2xy} 2}\cdot p_Ydy$$

So for this to work, we need a marginal density $p_Y$ such that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {c_2}{c_1}\cdot e^{-\frac {y^2-2xy} 2}\cdot p_Ydy=1\quad\quad \text{for all }x\in \mathbb R$$

This seems impossible.

**But is there a way to show abstractly that this is impossible?** i.e. without going into the specifics of the normal distribution. (e.g. just on the basis of properties $1$ and $2$)

Comment: The only way it can be that $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $X | Y \sim N(y,1)$ is if $Y$ is a delta-function distribution at $y=0$. There is no MI in this case because the outcome of $Y$ provides no information (does not reduce uncertainty).

Comment: $I(X;Y)=0$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. This is a standard result in information theory. Any "counter-example" to this must have some "flaw" as you and the comment above demonstrated.

Comment: Actually the first comment you make is that $p_{X|Y}\neq p_X$ which is true in general but for independence it needs to be true $p_Y$-almost surely. The solution of your last equation is that $p_Y$ is actually the distribution of a constant $0$ which makes independence true.

Comment: ^A supplement to Stelios' comment since you wanted a proof - this follows from the equality condition of Jensen's inequality (and the fact that $\log$ is strictly concave).